# How to search a matching file and assign to a variable in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Need to assign the file name to a variable that matches the search pattern

The code below will list the files in the dir (good). Help. If a file name has the substring (or starts with)  "MW_MMP_MEMBER.." then it assigns the file name to a variable.

```
FOR %%I in (%MW_MMP_data%*.*) DO echo %%I 

SET MEMBERFILE= ??
ECHO MEMBERFILE
```

I expect the `ECHO` statement to display the matching file

Comment: Try this. `FOR %%I in (*MW_MMP_MEMBER*.*) DO SET MEMBERFILE=%%I`

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir/B/A-D "MW_MMP_MEMBER*" 2^>Nul')Do @Set "MemberFile=%%A"&Call Echo(%%MemberFile%%&Pause
```

Or in a less shortened format:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In (
    'Dir /B /A-D "MW_MMP_MEMBER*" 2^>Nul'
) Do (
    Set "MemberFile=%%A"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo(!MemberFile!
    EndLocal
)
Pause
```